# Change Background color of an item in ListView onscroll?

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

hello there i have a listview contains many items on it but only 3 items are visible and i want to change the background color of the middle item after scrolling the list

my `Activity` implements  `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` and i have 2 override methods as shown below

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    int firstVisibleRow = AccountList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastVisibleRow = AccountList.getLastVisiblePosition();
    int middleone = firstVisibleRow+1;

        Account test = (Account) AccountList.getItemAtPosition(middleone);
       // test is the item in the middle of listview 

        Log.i("", "" + middleone + "=" + test.getDescription());
}
```

I create array list of Account and adapter of Account list 
Account test  is the middle item

and i got it critical as i need 
now i want to set background color to this row "test"

please any help wish i was clear in my question 
thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first thank you all

finally i found my solution here is it

```
  @Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    wantedView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_shape);//or color but set background 
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    int middlePosition = AccountList.getFirstVisiblePosition()+1;
    int firstPosition = AccountList.getFirstVisiblePosition() - AccountList.getHeaderViewsCount();
    int middleChild = middlePosition - firstPosition;

    if (middleChild < 0 || middleChild >= AccountList.getChildCount()) {
        Log.w("TAG", " Unable to get view for desired position, because its not being displayed on screen");
        return;
    }
    middleView = AccountList.getChildAt(middleChild);
    middleView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



}
```

good luck for all  :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your [int middleone] a global variable (declare it before onCreate()  )

and than use this code:

```
 @Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    AccountList.get(middleone).setBackgroundColor(YOURCOLOR);
}
```

Comment: sorry but test is an object of Account it's data type not view i want to set background for the view witch contain the test object

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that did the trick,

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int pos = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();               
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) list.findViewWithTag(pos++);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Log.v("inside", "inside" + layout.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView a,int arg1,int arg2,int arg3){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

and the getView looks like,

```
if(convertView==null){
LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.linear.setTag(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(s[position]);
        holder.tv2.setText(s1[position]);
```

Please note, I ran into a ClassCastException in the end, but this is the way to go. Do let me know when you find the way through it.